# How can I implement the new iPad Pro Keyboard Shortcuts feature?

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard-shortcuts

[Apple's iPad Pro page](http://www.apple.com/smart-keyboard/) talks about a new keyboard shortcut feature:

> ## Shortcuts at your fingertips.
>
> iOS 9 works seamlessly with the Smart Keyboard, adding a variety of useful QuickType features to your iPad Pro.
>
> [image]
>
> Time-saving Shortcuts
>
> Use keyboard shortcuts to perform even more commands on your iPad Pro — like switching between apps or bringing up search with your Smart Keyboard. And interact with your apps using their own built-in custom shortcuts. Just press and hold a key like Command, Option, or Control to see shortcuts in any app.

I tried searching the [iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html) and [iOS 9.1](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016572-SW1) API pages and can't find anything about keyboard shortcuts.

How can I implement this feature in my app, or where can I find the documentation that talks about it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like most of this feature had already existed as of iOS 7, called [UIKeyCommand](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyCommand_class/).

The only thing that was added is the [discoverabilityTitle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyCommand_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIKeyCommand/discoverabilityTitle), which is used to display the available command names on any iPad running iOS 9+.  You can see this menu in the simulator by holding down the command key on any screen that provides keyboard shortcuts (e.g. the iOS home screen).

[image]

There's a [nice write up on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uikeycommand/) about this, which includes these iOS 9 features.

Essentially you need to do the following:

1. Allow the view controller to become first responder.
2. Return an array of UIKeyCommands in the view controller's `keyCommands` method.
3. Handle the action that is sent to the view controller.